# how to preventDefault in componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Trying to update state after I call an api but I need to preventDefault so my form doesn't trigger a page reload. I am having a hard time finding information to be able to do this with React in the way that i'm trying it.

Trying it this way i get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined"

```
<form className="form-inline" onSubmit={this.componentDidMount} >
       <input
          placeholder="Search your city!"
          className="form-control"
          value={this.state.term}
          onChange={this.onInputChange}></input>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>

componentDidMount(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const API_KEY = 'ju2nvu4nvun42vgrw';
    const ROOT_URL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?
                      appid=${API_KEY}`;
    const city = this.state.term;
    const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city}`;
    axios.get(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            this.setState({
                days: response.data
            })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount` is a `lifeCycle` function, you should not call the function directly, instead move you ajax request in a separate function and call it like

```
<form className="form-inline" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
       <input
          placeholder="Search your city!"
          className="form-control"
          value={this.state.term}
          onChange={this.onInputChange}></input>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const API_KEY = 'ju2nvu4nvun42vgrw';
    const ROOT_URL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?
                      appid=${API_KEY}`;
    const city = this.state.term;
    const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city}`;
    axios.get(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            this.setState({
                days: response.data
            })
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help